# graphing several lines of same function in R

Tags: r

So I am trying to add some graphs to my notes of different functions.
Below is a simple interest function that gives the accumulated value of `1$` at time `t` with interest rate `i`. When I plot it, the initial function `avSimple(0.075,t)` looks fine but the addition ploted lines from the `lines` command plots the lines *red* & *blue* lines one unit to the right.
But they should all have a common point at `t = 0`, `AV = 1`.

What is going on here? I'm fairly new to this so I hope this isn't a dumb question.

```
# AV Simple Interest
avSimple = function(i,t){
    av = (1 + (i * t))
    return(av)}

t = 0:50
plot(t,avSimple(0.075,t), type="l", main = "AV Simple Interest", 
    xlab = "Time", ylab = "AV")   # This plots good
lines(avSimple(0.05,t), col = "red")  #This is shifted to right
lines(avSimple(0.025,t), col = "blue")  #This is also shifted right
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using lines you should specify both the `x` and `y` values. If you only specify one value, R will assume those are `y` values and will set `x=seq_along(y)` (which will start at 1). You should be doing

```
t = 0:50
plot(t,avSimple(0.075,t), type="l", main = "AV Simple Interest", 
    xlab = "Time", ylab = "AV")   # This plots good
lines(t, avSimple(0.05,t), col = "red")  #This is shifted to right
lines(t, avSimple(0.025,t), col = "blue")
```